# Останов в случае исключения в FireBug

Tags: javascript, firebug

Как поставить точку останова на исключение (exception breakpoint) в отладчике FireBug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [service.trackThrowCatch](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Preferences):

> Script Panel Options Mini Menu->Track Throw/Catch